# Error when installing Thingsboard on Azure AKS - PSQLException: The connection attempt fail

Tags: java, postgresql, azure-aks, thingsboard

I run the script from Azure VM, trying to install with azure/microservices file but keep failing.

```
  SPRING_JPA_DATABASE_PLATFORM: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
  SPRING_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME: org.postgresql.Driver
  SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://my-app-postgresql.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/myapp?user=myappusername&password=mypass?sslmode=require
  SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: myappusername
  SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD:  mypass
```

Then I run ./k8s-install-tb.sh, this error pop up:

> Installing DataBase schema for entities...

> Installing SQL DataBase schema part: schema-entities.sql

> Unexpected error during ThingsBoard installation!

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.org.thingsboard.server.service.install.SqlAbstractDatabaseSchemaService.executeQueryFromFil

> Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out

Hope someone can help me out with this. Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue after following this tutorial:
https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/install/cluster/azure-microservices-setup/
But when I was doing this tutorial I had changed this command:

```
az aks create --resource-group $AKS_RESOURCE_GROUP \
    --name $TB_CLUSTER_NAME \
    --generate-ssh-keys \
    --enable-addons ingress-appgw \
    --appgw-name $AKS_GATEWAY \
    --appgw-subnet-cidr "10.2.0.0/16" \
    --node-vm-size Standard_DS3_v2 \
    --node-count 3
```

so I didn't have to upgrade my subscription, that was causing it to fail. It worked when I increased my CPU allowance from 10 to 12